# Filter event ethers.js sample code not working

Tags: events, ethers.js, filters

I've been trying to follow the [Listening to Events sample code](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--events) and make a filter that detects when a specific address receives BUSD instead of DAI. However, it doesn't seem to do any filtering and logs Transfer events for other addresses as well. I used ethers version 5.5.1 to test the samples of code below.

**Attempt 1**

```js
const ercTokenAddress = "0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56"; // BUSD
const abi = [
  "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)"
];
const contract = new Contract(ercTokenAddress, abi, provider);

// A filter for when a specific address receives tokens
let filter = contract.filters.Transfer(null, recipient)
// Receive an event when that filter occurs
contract.on(filter, (from, to, amount, event) => {
    console.log(`to: ${to}`)
});
```

Sample results:

```
to: 0xc2b068161D308AB9794098992Ad036B23E0B57FB
to: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16
to: 0xc590175E458b83680867AFD273527Ff58f74c02b
to: 0x71C292269718BC1e38EdF6023Fb427D35924389E
to: 0x5822a13D770675402707A9215215F1d5EE6646Df
to: 0x2e707261d086687470B515B320478Eb1C88D49bb
to: 0x978c47e98E038b37E4F0c0b48D08b752BaeD8469
to: 0xbAF9A5d4b0052359326A6CDAb54BABAa3a3A9643
to: 0x1B96B92314C44b159149f7E0303511fB2Fc4774f
```

**Attempt 2**

I have also tried specifying both sender and recipient addresses as in the answer to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106737/83032):

```js
let filter = contract.filters.Transfer(sender, recipient)
contract.on(filter, (from, to, amount, event) => {
    console.log(`from: ${from} | to: ${to}`)
});
```

Sample results:

```
from: 0xd5c20E79D9cd9DD697526e2a41447f3ACa91f84A | to: 0xc58b4e438d338Ce31eC0C91f1aA8287A7409070A
from: 0x025C26c69B939bb4c19635146ea7106D92575556 | to: 0xC63B0d319b926CC6380164214E3E2056C76cD3D7
from: 0xc73158584A89153065F37C5a5372d51aa06e949E | to: 0x2b92C42462672A13106c0867C67E1Af22328e694
from: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16 | to: 0x4913b6a41D4B41DD587EBb99B11cF01fB3c3d90d
from: 0xDBAeE0c1012896758f596fE8eaAB2C8Ffa49E4fe | to: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16
from: 0xd76026a78a2A9aF2f9F57fe6337eED26Bfc26AED | to: 0x873F73f60756eA5Fb687627670088b4B7613C92c
from: 0xBbd923e6Ffed3A6Ed1497e8Ed4921145ff94E3db | to: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16
from: 0x213f7E7Fe55e59B526b5255270Fc0F665Fb36B57 | to: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16
from: 0x05faf555522Fa3F93959F86B41A3808666093210 | to: 0xd76026a78a2A9aF2f9F57fe6337eED26Bfc26AED
from: 0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16 | to: 0xB72723e36a83FB5Fe1793f06b436F4720F5DE4F9
```

Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the events seems to be working or you wouldnt get anything printed, what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was expecting the filters to filter the event by the specified addresses, but they're all different. Attempt 1 should only show a single address. Attempt 2 should show the same two addresses every time.